# redis-server2 is start-stop-daemon: warning: this system is not able to track process names longer than 15 characters

Tags: service, init.d, redis

So I've had the need of running 2 instances of redis in the same server. My server is an Ubuntu 14.04 box.

So I followed [this guide](http://makandracards.com/makandra/7965-run-multiple-redis-servers-on-ubuntu), but not in a strict way. I mean, instead of modifying redis init scripts (that come from Ubuntu packages) I decided to create new scripts for the 2nd instance, and leave the original ones untouched for the first instance.

So then, what I did is:

1) Create new script for new instance (it will run in the 6380 port, instead of the default 6379 one):

```
sudo cp /etc/init.d/redis-server /etc/init.d/redis-server6380
```

2) Modify /etc/init.d/redis-server6380 to be a bit different. Instead of:

```
DAEMON=/usr/bin/redis-server
DAEMON_ARGS=/etc/redis/redis.conf
NAME=redis-server
DESC=redis-server

RUNDIR=/var/run/redis
PIDFILE=$RUNDIR/redis-server.pid
```

It would have:

```
NAME=`basename ${0}`
DAEMON=/usr/bin/redis-server
DAEMON_ARGS=/etc/redis/${NAME}.conf
DESC=${NAME}

RUNDIR=/var/run/redis
PIDFILE=$RUNDIR/${NAME}.pid
```

3) Then copy the configuration:

```
cp /etc/redis/redis-server.conf /etc/redis/redis-server6380.conf
```

Edit the new redis-server6380.conf file to be from:

```
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid
port 6379
logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server.log
dir /var/lib/redis
```

To:

```
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-server6380.pid
port 6380
logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server6380.log
dir /var/lib/redis6380
```

4) Then create the working directory:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/redis6380 && sudo chown redis.redis /var/lib/redis6380
```

The slight problem I have now, is that it's kind of difficult to check if the instances are runnning.

Before, I guess I could just run:

```
service redis-server status
```

And know whether redis is running.

Now, if I do that, I get:

```
$ service redis-server status
redis-server is not running
```

Even when the first instance is running! And for the 2nd instance I get:

```
$ service redis-server6380 status
redis-server6380 is start-stop-daemon: warning: this system is not able to track process
names longer than 15 characters, please use --exec instead of --name.
not running
```

BUT WHY? I don't understand...

Same thing happens if I use `/etc/init.d/redis-server*` instead of `service`. The hacky way I now know to check if they are really running is this:

```
$ ps aux | grep redis
andrew     365  0.0  0.1  10468  2236 pts/0    S+   07:17   0:00 grep --color=auto redis
redis    22521  0.0  1.3  50860 23132 ?        Ssl  Feb19   4:38 /usr/bin/redis-server 0.0.0.0:6379
redis    52953  0.0  0.5  38572  8860 ?        Ssl  Feb25   0:23 /usr/bin/redis-server 0.0.0.0:6380
```

But I would like to not need to resort to this :(